# Injecting service VS Injecting mongoose model in nestjs

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I am trying to use a model in a different service, and I have two options of injection

Is there a different or a best practice in this case?!

injecting the service which contains the model

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Office.modelName, schema: Office.model.schema }]),
    AuthModule,
    forwardRef(() => OrganizationsModule),
  ],
  providers: [OfficeService],
  controllers: [OfficeController],
  exports: [OfficeService],
})
```

vs injecting the model again

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Office.modelName, schema: Office.model.schema }]),
    AuthModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Organization.modelName, schema: Organization.model.schema }]),
  ],
  providers: [OfficeService],
  controllers: [OfficeController],
  exports: [OfficeService],
})
```

Comment: I believe the proper approach would be to import the already-defined "OrganizationsModule" into your OfficeModule instead of simply importing the Mongoose module again. That being said, if you were planning on doing some fancy join queries, you may need the raw model imported but the first approach is the correct one.